# Conditional dataframe mutations in R with magrittr and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

I would like to use the succinctness of magrittr and dplyr to copy single values between rows in a subset of columns based on the values in other columns. This is a simple example; I want to apply this idea to many columns of a large dataset with multiple conditions within a long pipe of commands.

Take the dataframe `df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10, x = 11:15, y = 16:20)`:

```
a   b   x   y

1   6   11  16
2   7   12  17
3   8   13  18
4   9   14  19
5   10  15  20
```

For the row where `a = 5`, I would like to replace the values of `x` and `y` with those in the row where `b = 7`, to give:

```
a   b   x   y

1   6   11  16
2   7   12  17
3   8   13  18
4   9   14  19
5   10  12  17
```

This attempt fails:

```
foo <- function(x){ifelse(df$a == 5, df[df$b == 7, .(df$x)], x)}
df %<>%  mutate_each(funs(foo), x, y)
```

The closest I can get is:

```
bar <- function(x){ifelse(df$a == 5, df[df$b == 7, "x"], x)}
df %<>%  mutate_each(funs(bar), x, y)
```

but this is incorrect as it replaces both values with the value from `x`, rather than `x` and `y` respectively.

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: what's the dooffernece between `%<>%` and `%>%`?

Comment: `x %<>% f` comes from the `magrittr` package and is equivalent to the common pattern `x <- x %>% f`.

Comment: `%>%` also comes from `magrittr` package...

Comment: @DavidArenburg `%>%` will work with only `dplyr` loaded while, at the moment and with the CRAN version, using `%<>%` necessitates to have `magrittr` loaded. True, `%>%` comes from `magrittr` through `dplyr`, but to the end-user knowing which packages to load is more relevant!

Comment: @antoine-sac well, that's just, like, your opinion, man.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do it using `mutate_each` and `replace`:

```
df %>% mutate_each(funs(replace(., a==5, nth(., which(b==7)))), x, y)
```

Output:

```
  a  b  x  y
1 1  6 11 16
2 2  7 12 17
3 3  8 13 18
4 4  9 14 19
5 5 10 12 17
```

Or as per @docendodiscimus 's comment it can be shortened further to (and probably `[` is also better than `which`):

```
df %>% mutate_each(funs(replace(., a==5, .[b==7])), x, y)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to apply this method to a large number of columns, potentially defined elsewhere, so this would rapidly become unwieldy.

Comment: @PatrickHogan I didn't notice this in your question. I might be able to tweak the above code.

Comment: Updated the answer. Now I think this should fit your needs.

Comment: Nice one! could possibly be shortened to `df %>% mutate_each(funs(replace(., a==5, .[b==7])), x, y)`

Comment: Aahh nice improvement @docendodiscimus thanks. I ll add it too.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for — thank you very much!

Comment: You are very welcome @PatrickHogan . Glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 9):

Just to mention the `data.table` solution would be:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)[a == 5, c("x", "y") := df[b == 7, .SD, .SDcols = c("x", "y")]]

> df
   a  b  x  y
1: 1  6 11 16
2: 2  7 12 17
3: 3  8 13 18
4: 4  9 14 19
5: 5 10 12 17
```

Alternatively, you could also use:

```
cols <- c("x", "y")
setDT(df)[a == 5, (cols) := df[b == 7, .SD, .SDcols = cols]]
# or 
cols <- c("x", "y")
setDT(df)[a == 5, (cols) := df[b == 7, cols, with = FALSE]]
```

Comment: `DT <- setDT(df)` makes little to no sense really.. since `df` is also now a data.table and has been updated by reference.

Comment: @Arun: I totally agree. When i started using `data.table` the _updating by reference_ concept was very strange to me. As the question asks for a `dplyr` solution i thought i make my answer a little bit more understandable.

Comment: I see.. Better to use as.data.table then. Also using `with=FALSE` or `.SD + .SDcols` would help show that it is easily extensible to many cols.

Comment: @Arun: Have a look at my edit. I do not understand what you mean by using `with=FALSE`. Feel free to edit.

Comment: Nice, thanks! This can also be piped: `df %<>% as.data.table %>% .[a == 5, c("x", "y") := .[b == 7, .SD, .SDcols = c("x", "y")]]`

Comment: I took the liberty to improve your answer. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 5):

If your main requirement is to apply the function within a longer dplyr-pipe, you could do something like the following example:

```
foo <- function(df, cols = c("x", "y")) {
  df[df$a == 5, cols] <- df[df$b == 7, cols]
  df
}

df %>% ... %>% foo(c("x", "y")) %>% ... 
#  a  b  x  y
#1 1  6 11 16
#2 2  7 12 17
#3 3  8 13 18
#4 4  9 14 19
#5 5 10 12 17
```